# Has the quadruple gluon vertex of QCD been observed experimentally?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, gluons

QCD has triple and quadruple gluon vertices in Feynman diagrams.

Has the quadruple gluon vertex been observed? For example, did jet events confirm it? Or did some other experiments see evidence for four-gluon vertices?

In the 1990s, various papers appeared which confirmed the observation of *triple* gluon vertices.

No experimental papers exists for the *four-gluon* vertex. The effect of the 4-gluon vertex seems to be hard to measure, also in jets. Is there any preliminary data on this?

I will offer a bounty again (I did so once, but with no success) for any reference on experiments that go into that direction.

Comment: Why do you think all tests of QCD could've still gotten the right answer without that vertex?

Comment: @Connor Behan I added part of my reasons in the question. The other reason is that I do not know which effect is sensitive to the four-gluon vertex. That is precisely the question ...

Comment: @Connor Behan: Individual terms in the SM Lagrangian have to be probed in isolation for the full theory to be verified. Several Higgs terms haven't been observed with sufficient statistical significance. In addition, higher order QCD theoretical predictions are still a developing field. The question posed here is a legitimate one.

Comment: "Of all elementary vertices that appear in the QCD Lagrangian, the four-gluon vertex is
the most poorly understood." https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.3677.pdf

Comment: Indeed high order QCD calculations are hard but $O(g^2)$ where the four gluon vertex first enters is not especially high. Are you saying it would be possible to pretend that it is absent and still see something like https://cerncourier.com/wp-content/uploads/2004/11/CCEasy2_11-04.jpg which agrees well with experiment?

Comment: Yes, QCD calculations do show contributions from 4-gluon vertex is smal and experimental observations support this. But that does not address the question "Has the quadruple gluon vertex been observed?", which is what OP asked.

Comment: This vertex is difficult to tackle theoretically. To guide diffent theory approaches, experiments need to probe channels that are dominated by this vertex or at least are able to estimate its contribution with precision. Present results do not achieve that.